# In google appmaker, can't get requestAnimationFrame working

Tags: javascript, animation, requestanimationframe, google-app-maker

wondering if anyone else noticing this. I can get an animation working using setInterval, but the timing isn't as precise as I'd like it to be. But for some reason, I can't get requestAnimationFrame to do much of anything.

The intention of the code below is to have the screen flash between 2 different colors every 250ms, though that's not really what I'm trying to achieve in the end, I'm using this simplified concept to just try to get the concept of animation working. (if anyone wants to take a crack at it, I'm trying to get a black background to flash red for 100ms, every 400ms).

Admittedly, I'm fairly new to javascript, but I'm wondering if anyone else has noticed anything like this?

code I'm attempting, onClick of button calls sayHello();

```
function sayHello(){
  var start = window.performance.now();
  var runStart = window.performance.now();
  var my_canvas = app.pages.Run.children.Panel1.children.Canvas.getElement().getElementsByTagName("CANVAS")[0];
  var requestId1;
  var totalDuration = 5000;
  var currentColor = '#000000';

  function animate1(now){
    my_canvas.style.backgroundColor = currentColor;
    console.log('animate now: ' + now + 'win' + windows.performance.now());
    if (now > start+250){
      start = now;
      now = 0;
      if (currentColor === '#ff0000') currentColor = '#000000';
      else currentColor = '#ff0000';
      console.log('switch: ' + window.performance.now());
    }

    if ((window.performance.now - runStart) > totalDuration){
      window.cancelAnimationFrame(requestId1); 
      console.log('done');
    }
    else{
      requestAnimationFrame(animate1);
      console.log('not done');
    }
  }

  function sayGoodbye(){
    window.cancelAnimationFrame(requestId1);
  }

  requestId1 = requestAnimationFrame(animate1);
  console.log('start app' + requestId1);
  console.log('info: ' + start + ' ' + runStart + ' ' + totalDuration);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You were almost there.

Just replace

> window**s**.performance.now()

with

> window.performance.now()

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the heads up - I did actually catch that and correct it, but still no luck getting requestAnimationFrame to work in AppMaker.

Comment: interestingly, my code apparently works in javascript. It's something specifically about google appmaker that prevents my code from running correctly. I created a website with my script included and it's running fine. Not sure what's up.